# Is there a way to avoid inputting username when git push with HTTPS?

Tags: git, github

I just want to input the password only. Is there a way to avoid inputting username when git push with HTTPS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Git 1.7 and higher you can define your username and password before the address. Something like that:

```
git config remote.origin.url https://you:password@github.com/your/example.git
```

then you can define your user and password and don't need to enter them every time.

Comment: Thx! It works after `git config remote.origin.url https://username@github.com/your/example.git`